# How to run a progress bar for a disk scanning process in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, progress-bar

Recently I have started to create a desktop based application which is for the scanning the PC. I have achieved this and it works great. However i would like to add a progress bar so that the user may know the amount of progress in a scan the application has done.

I have worked on using a progress bar for normal functions where the Minimum value and Maximum values are known. But during the scan process I have the minimum value as 0 but how can i assume the maximum value?

I tried counting all the files inside a particular drive but its not that efficient moreover there are few directories permission to accessing which are denied. So how can I go up with getting the Maximum value for the scan. How can i make the Progress bar work for this particular situation. I have seen many application where once the process ends the progress bar is also at the ending stage.

Answer (score 0):

The progress bar shows the percentage of task completion.You can get maximum bounds using

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles(drivePath, "*.mp3", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Count()
```

This is lighter weight.

Comment: Can u elaborate a little im still not able to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider the [drive totalbytes and capacity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.getdrives.aspx) and then use the size in bytes of the file you just processed you can show progress on the number of bytes to process. This only works if you only backup the whole disk.

Here you have a more complete and working example for a WinForms type of app which uses a [backgroundworker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) and a [progressbar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.aspx). There is no start penalty because Disk size is readily available.

```
private long diskSizeInGB = 1;
const long GB = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
long filesizesProcessedInGB = 0;

private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // get drive info
    var cdrive = DriveInfo.GetDrives().First(d => d.Name == @"C:\");
    // calculate max used bytes
    diskSizeInGB = (cdrive.TotalSize - cdrive.TotalFreeSpace) / GB;
    // backupprocess, async!
    bgwScan.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void bgwScan_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Scanner(@"C:\"); // start scaning/backuping/copying recursively
}

void Scanner(string path)
{
    foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.*"))
    {
        var fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);
        filesizesProcessedInGB += (fileInfo.Length / GB);  
        // Copy / backup / whatever you want with a file
    }
    // calculate progress percentager and report
    bgwScan.ReportProgress((int)(100 * filesizesProcessedInGB / diskSizeInGB));

    foreach (var dir in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path))
    {
        try
        {
            Scanner(dir);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(dir + " error");
        }
    }
}

private void bgwScan_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // update progressbar
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
```

Comment: Im really not able to get this thing. I followed this piece of code
 http://softwaretipz.com/softwaretipz.com/obtaining-the-file-count-of-directorydrive-using-c-sharp/ its still not working properly for me. Now im able to get the count but still it takes time for me. Isnt there anything faster that this?

Comment: You don't want to Count because tyat is NOT instantly available. Use Disksize and filesize because disksize IS instantly available. You calculate progress based on the **filesize** processed, not on the number of files processed.

Comment: But the whole process that im using is of the file processing. Means i would have to change the logic. Or for every file that is being processed i have to take the amount total filesize then increase the progress bar step by step.

Comment: Yes, you have to change your logic to consider filesizes as shown in my current sample. You can call your processing at the line with my comment that says `// Copy / backup / whatever you want with a file`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your guidance rene. It seems good to proceed this way. Im already on it. Seems a better solution than before.